# Adding Contact's Custom field & Showing Total on Accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, roll-up-summary

Since the Roll-up Summary option does not work from Contacts to Accounts..

I have a custom number field on the Contact level (let's call it ABC), and I want to create a Field on the Account to show the total of all the ABC fields from all related Contacts to an Account.  Can this be done without triggers?

Comment: can you check this https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Declarative_Rollup_Summary_Tool_for_Force.com_Lookup_Relationships

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the LREngine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified the above trigger you mentioned to update the Account field with SUM of all its related contact Custom Field.
Replace the Field_On_Contact__c with Contact Field API name and Field_On_Account__c with Account Field API name.

```
trigger ContactSumTrigger on Contact (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update) {

Contact[] cons;
if (Trigger.isDelete) 
    cons = Trigger.old;
else
    cons = Trigger.new;

Set<ID> acctIds = new Set<ID>();
for (Contact con : cons) {
   acctIds.add(con.AccountId);
}

Map<ID, Contact> contactsForAccounts = new Map<ID, Contact>([SELECT Id ,AccountId, Field_On_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :acctIds]);

Map<ID, Account> acctsToUpdate = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Field_On_Account__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :acctIds]);

for (Account acct : acctsToUpdate.values()) {
Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
Decimal totalValue = 0;
for (Contact con : contactsForAccounts.values()) {
    if (con.AccountId == acct.Id && con.Field_On_Contact__c != NULL) {
        totalValue += con.Field_On_Contact__c; 
    }
}
acc.Field_On_Account__c = totalValue;
}
if(acctsToUpdate.values().size() > 0) {
    update acctsToUpdate.values();
}
}
```

Hope this will help You.

Comment: Thanks AKSHAY; however should the Number_of_Contacts__c be replaced with Field_On_Account__c ?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry that was my mistake.  In query replace that.

Comment: I replaced it, however now I am getting an error Compile Error: unexpected token: where at line 19 column 77

Comment: Thank you I was able to replace it and save it.  However, when I update the contact field to test it I am getting the following error:

Error:Apex trigger ContactSumTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContactSumTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Number__c: ()

Comment: Try it again. I have made the change.

Comment: Happy to know that it helped you. ☺️

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer the Question, but here is a compact solution for the Question.
As a best practice I have provided the code of the Handler class of the Trigger. 
You just need to call this method, whenever you need to update the records.

```
 public void rollupAccount(){
    Set<Id> accIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    
    // Here, isDelete = trigger.isDelete, recordOldList = trigger.old and recordNewList = trigger.new
    for(contact con : isDelete ? recordOldList : recordNewList ){
        accIdSet.add(con.AccountId);
    }
    
    // Fetching the Account List to update.
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    accList = [ SELECT Id, Total_Amount__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: accIdSet ];

    if(accList.size() > 0 ){
    
        // Querying all the contact related to account, grouped by each Account, So here we will get Account Id and Sum from the related contact
        // We are using Aggregate Query, So no need to use any variable to hold the total amount.
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> accAggrigateMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([ SELECT SUM(Amount__c) totalAmount, AccountId Id 
                                                                                    FROM Contact 
                                                                                   WHERE AccountId =: accIdSet 
                                                                                GROUP BY AccountId ]);
        for(Account ac : accList ){
            ac.Total_Amount__c = ( (Decimal) accAggrigateMap.get(ac.Id).get('totalAmount') );
        }
        update accList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Rollup Helper Free Edition - A Helper Suite App](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI)
which provides following functionalities:

> Rollup Helper rolls-up any Salesforce data. Supports count, sum, max, min, average, percent, lookup rollups, text, and multi-currency.

And its free.

Comment: With the Rollup Helper Free edition - you have to trigger it each time and you only get 3 "tries".  I would require something that's more ongoing.

Comment: Then you can simply write a trigger

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to help me with the trigger?
I was able to find the Trigger to count number of Contacts:

```
trigger ContactSumTrigger on Contact (after delete, after insert, after undelete,
```

after update) {

```
Contact[] cons;
if (Trigger.isDelete) 
    cons = Trigger.old;
else
    cons = Trigger.new;

// get list of accounts
Set<ID> acctIds = new Set<ID>();
for (Contact con : cons) {
        acctIds.add(con.AccountId);
}

Map<ID, Contact> contactsForAccounts = new Map<ID, Contact>([select Id
                                                        ,AccountId
                                                        from Contact
                                                        where AccountId in :acctIds]);

Map<ID, Account> acctsToUpdate = new Map<ID, Account>([select Id
                                                             ,Number_of_Contacts__c
                                                              from Account
                                                              where Id in :acctIds]);

for (Account acct : acctsToUpdate.values()) {
    Set<ID> conIds = new Set<ID>();
    for (Contact con : contactsForAccounts.values()) {
        if (con.AccountId == acct.Id)
            conIds.add(con.Id);
    }
    if (acct.Number_of_Contacts__c != conIds.size())
        acct.Number_of_Contacts__c = conIds.size();
}

update acctsToUpdate.values();
```

}

Can I update this to just count the custom field within the Contact?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this without writing your own trigger, and don't want to use Rollup Helper Free Edition, you could instead consider Andrew Fawcett's **Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries** app, which is 100% free and can accomplish your goal.

It (just like Rollup Helper), DOES use triggers, but it allows you to create these rollups without advanced trigger knowledge through a pretty simple to use UI within Salesforce

https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries

Comment: More Info on DLRS: [here](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/02/16/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries-tool-dlrs-spring15-release/)

Answer (score -2):

```
trigger Task2Income on Contact (after update,after insert,after delete,after undelete) {
    List<Contact> ContactsLst;
    set<String> vAccId = new set<String>();
    if(!trigger.isdelete) ContactsLst = trigger.new;
    else ContactsLst = trigger.old;
    for(Contact vContact : ContactsLst){
        if(vContact.AccountId != null){
            vAccId.add(vContact.AccountId);
        }
    }
            list<Contact> op=[select id, Primary_Income__c, from Contact where AccountId 
             in:vAccId];
            list<Account> acc=[select id,Total_Primary_Income__c,  from account where id 
             in:vAccId];

             for(Account a:acc){
                decimal pSum=0;
                for(Contact o:op){
                  if(o.Primary_Income__c != null)
                    pSum += o.Primary_Income__c;
                }
                a.Total_Primary_Income__c = pSum;
            }
            update acc;
}
```

Comment: This answer is what we call a _code dump_, it's a block of code with no explanation about how it works or solves the problem. Code dumps tend to make poor answers because they don't help people understand how to solve the problem at hand, and tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" which makes it hard for other people with similar issues to follow.